# Testing IPV6 Networks Macbook Pro (No Ethernet Port)

Tags: ios, react-native, ipv6

Submitting an app using `react-native@0.34.1` and am getting denied from the app store for not supporting IPV6 connections.

I have seen this article [React Native: App Store Rejection, Support for IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783443/react-native-app-store-rejection-support-for-ipv6)

and also http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

but I am having a difficult time testing this because I am on a macbook pro with no ports for an internet cable. Is there a way to test an iphone app when I primarily use wifi for internet?

Comment: If your wifi isn't IPv6 itself then you will need a USB to Ethernet dongle to create an IPv6 network. You should confirm that IPv6 is actually the problem though. Sometimes there is some other problem an error the rejection messGe just mentions IPv6 as a description of the test environment.

Comment: @Paulw11 - do you have any other recommendations for testing different things that could go wrong apart from the IPv6 environment?

Comment: You need to look at then rejection notice and see what problem they described. See if you can reproduce it with a TestFlight build. It may be an iov6 issue. Does your app access a server?

Comment: I cant reproduce it in testflight. The rejection notice is:

Thank you for your resubmission. However upon further review we still find that we were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing.

Comment: Have you looked at the crash log?  Is it crashing in a network operation?  If it is then you will need to test on iov6 and resolve the issue.